# Building IntelliSense/AutoComplete in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, google-chrome, intellisense, firefox-addon

I currently maintain an add-on for Firefox that adds a number of capabilities to a forum web site that implements its own markup language, similar to what stackoverflow provides with "Markdown."

I have built an IntelliSense function for this add-on, which, similar to Visual Studio, will pop up an auto-suggest when typing this markup in a textarea. Example:

http://members.lycos.co.uk/suffusion/namfox/faq-1.5/autocomplete-example-2-1.jpg

The hardest thing about the implementation is finding the (x,y) coordinates of a key press in a textarea so I can pop-up the IntelliSense window very close to it. The keypress events in JavaScript do not expose these coordinates, so I've had to work around this. Unfortunately I could only find a cross-browser compatible way of getting the y-coordinate, not the x-coordinate. The code for this is located [here](http://code.google.com/p/namfox/source/browse/trunk/chrome/content/enhancements/auto-complete/AutoCompleteController.js#281) in the _getPopupPoint function.

This works for Firefox because I use some of Mozilla's XPCOM interfaces to get the coordinate. So while this works for Firefox, now that I want to port my add-on to Google Chrome, I couldn't find a way to get the coordinates.

So what I'm asking is twofold:
(1) Is there a better way to get the x-coordinate of a key press?
(2) If not, is there anything I can do in the context of a Google Chrome add-on to get the same data?

Comment: +1 because of releasing code, and in order for you to attach images

Comment: Thanks! Just posted the image.

Answer (score 1):

The [window.getSelection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Selection) and related methods might be what you're looking for. You can calculate the screen position of the caret using the offset etc functions.

Comment: This looks close to what I want. However, the anchorOffset and focusOffset properties reset to 0 at the beginning of every line feed character. This means if the user types a paragraph I can't accurately find the x-coordinate because the paragraph spans multiple lines in the text area.

Answer (score 0):

It coculd be interesting to checkout the implementation of [event object in DOJO toolkit](http://docs.dojocampus.org/quickstart/events).

Dojo provides the following attributes with an event object:

- event.target - the element that generated the event
- event.currentTarget - the current target
- event.layerX - the x coordinate, relative to the event.currentTarget
- event.layerY - the y coordinate, relative to the event.currentTarget
- event.pageX - the x coordinate, relative to the view port
- event.pageY - the y coordinate, relative to the view port
- event.relatedTarget - For onmouseover and onmouseout, the object that the mouse pointer is moving to or out of
- event.charCode - For keypress events, the character code of the key pressed
- event.keyCode - for keypress events, handles special keys like ENTER and spacebar.
- event.charOrCode - a normalized version of charCode and keyCode, which can be used for direct comparison for alpha keys and special keys together. (added in 1.1)

Comment: The normal KeyboardEvent passed to a keypress event listener will have most of these properties, too, but the layerX/layerY and pageX/pageY properties are 0. I just tried with Dojo, and the properties also remain at 0.